# Magento 1.9.1.0 Package not found issues

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9.1

When trying to upgrade certain packages and core Magento some upgrades will give me this error:

> Package community/Magento_Mobile failed: Package release
>   'Magento_Mobile' not found on server

Anyone know how to fix this problem?